# How to merge an ongoing call with another number programmatically in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Merge an ongoing call with another number programmatically and create a conference (while other call is running).
Eg: Use Case: I am running a call with 121 number, when I dial a short #123 or press a button on my app, programmatically 456 is added to the call.